# Is there an equivalent of string-match for regexp?

Tags: regular-expressions

I'd like to write something like this except to compare the region with a regexp.

```
(if (string-match (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) (mark))
                  "foo")
    (bar))
```

Is there an equivalent of string-match for regexp that I can use like this

```
(if (regexp-match (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) (mark))
                  "^[A-Z]")
    (bar))
```

so that it returns true if the selected region is "Apple" and nil if it's "apple"?

Comment: A few random remarks : (i) `string-match` already uses regexps (ii) let-bind `case-fold-search` to nil around your call if you want case sensitivity (iii) use `looking-at` for matching text at point (iv) you can use `region-beginning` and `region-end` instead of `point` and `mark` in case the latter is before the former (bonus point for making sure `use-region-p` is non-nil)

Comment: @YoungFrom I think item (i) qualifies as an answer.

Comment: `C-h f` `string-match` would tell you.

Answer (score 11):

For the sake of an answer:

`string-match` is meant for to be used with regexps.

> (string-match REGEXP STRING &optional START)
>
> Return index of start of first match for REGEXP in STRING, or nil.
>   Matching ignores case if ‘case-fold-search’ is non-nil.
>   If third arg START is non-nil, start search at that index in STRING.
>   For index of first char beyond the match, do (match-end 0).
>   ‘match-end’ and ‘match-beginning’ also give indices of substrings
>   matched by parenthesis constructs in the pattern.
>
> You can use the function ‘match-string’ to extract the substrings
>   matched by the parenthesis constructions in REGEXP.

Here are some examples

```lisp
(string-match "\\(dog\\|cat\\)" "There is a dog.") ;; => 11
(string-match "\\(dog\\|cat\\)" "There are two cats here." 0) ;; => 14
(string-match "\\(dog\\|cat\\)" "There are two cats here." 15) ;; => nil
(string-match "\\(dog\\|cat\\)" "There are horses.") ;; => nil
```

Note that if you don't plan on using `match-data` after using `string-match` you should prefer to use `string-match-p` which works just like `string-match` except that it doesn't modify `match-data` when run.

As other have said, in your case `looking-at` would probably be a better choice anyway.

> (looking-at REGEXP)
>
> Return t if text after point matches regular expression REGEXP.
>   This function modifies the match data that ‘match-beginning’,
>   ‘match-end’ and ‘match-data’ access; save and restore the match
>   data if you want to preserve them.

Comment: Given that the OP got the argument order wrong, it would probably be a good idea to show an example snippet calling `string-match`.